# Как сделать высоту в 100%?

Tags: css, angularjs

Добрый день. Стандартный вопрос встал - как сделать блок в 100% высотой. Использую angular-material (соответственно, flexbox)

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center start" flex>
```

```
<section layout="column" hide-sm  flex>
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
</section>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UROiwBX58lTKxshBARnI?p=preview

Мне нужно, чтобы блок контента (отмечен в коде комментариями) - по максимуму прижимался к низу. Ну и, соответственно, два левых бока тоже растягивались.

Answer (score 1):

первое что пришло в голову с такой ацкой разметкой не меняя классы и прочее

`.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 64px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`

http://caniuse.com/#search=calc 
http://caniuse.com/#search=vm